# Ratio Between Voltage and Charge

Tags: batteries, discharge

Is there a ratio between the voltage and charge of a battery?

I mean, the voltage falls slowly while the charge is consumed? Or occurs a sudden drop of voltage when the charge is at the end?

Comment: What type of battery?

Comment: The question is about all types of batteries. But the Li-Po battery is of main interest.

Comment: The point of a battery is to provide a certain voltage, so batteries are designed to slowly drop in voltage as the state of charge decreases, yes. Towards the low charge end, there is often a sharper drop in voltage, yes. But the curve of voltage vs state of charge will differ depending on battery type/load. edit - Kynit is also correct in that it is not a ratio, you have to characterize it is a curve on a graph and even that won't be entirely accurate. Really what you want to do is use graphs provided by the battery manuf. to determine voltage @ charge states

Comment: In Li-ion batteries, it's not a simple ratio - there's more capacity at certain voltages (ie: if you pull out charge at a constant rate, the voltage will not change at a constant rate, but will speed up/slow down)

Answer (score 4):

Battery Voltage mostly depends on

1. State of charge
2. Current being drawn, because of internal resistance.
3. Temperature
4. Other aspects of its physical health, age, etc.

None of these are simple or linear.

- Voltage vs State of charge, you will find a chart for your chosen battery chemistry. It may have a nice slope (Lead acid) or it may be very flat for most of the discharge (lithium, NiCd), in which case the voltage gives very little useful information.
- Internal resistance should be specified for the actual battery. It also changes with the state of charge, you might find a chart of this. It might not be a linear resistor, and it does depend on the frequency of the current drawn.
- Temperature, will probably have a simple relationship, also in the datasheet.

Simple battery indicators will measure voltage, perhaps compensating for temperature.

Advances fuel gauges, like in your cellphone or laptop, actually count the charge in and out of the battery. They compare this cycle to a known previous cycle when the battery did actually run down. They take into account the charging efficiency, temperature and aging of the battery too.

The best advice I can give is to read the whole of [batteryuniversity.com](http://www.batteryuniversity.com). He knows simply everything about batteries and has taken some trouble to write the book about them. He even blogs about them, like when Boeing was in the news...
Also read some manufacturers' datasheets for the chemistry of your choice, to get an idea of the characteristics you can expect.